# Why is the mysqli PHP extension not working on RHEL?

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, rhel

I am using this script to check if mysqli is working:

```
<?php if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
```

I am seeing "We don't have mysqli!!!" in my browser.

But when I do...

```
php -m
```

...I see mysqli listed.  Meanwhile, I have confirmed that the extension is in the right directory...

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

The output is...

```
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

I have confirmed that there is an mysqli.so in /usr/lib64/php/modules.

I have tried all of the following things in php.ini:

```
extension=mysqli
extension=mysqli.so
extension=php_mysqli.so
extension=php_mysqli
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
```

None of these work.  I still get "We don't have mysqli!!!"

I am restarting Apache after each attempt.  I also tried clearing the browser cache and restarting the browser.

Comment: That function results in this error:  "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_get_client_info()."  The php -m command indicates mysqlnd is installed.  If I run 'yum install php7-mysqlnd' I get 'No package php7-mysqlnd available.'

Comment: `php -m` indicates `CLI SAPI` I don't know much about RHEL but on Ubuntu CLI has its own `php.ini` and the server has also it's own php ini file.

Comment: Fixed.  Like you said, I was checking the CLI with php -m.  So I printed php_ini_loaded_file() in a php file to get the real php,ini path. Once I had the right php.ini, I needed to add extension=mysqlnd  and  extension=mysqli in the php.ini.  Thanks!